# Empty property in Binding the GridViewColumn to List<EntityFrameworkCore's Entity>

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, entity-framework-core

- There is no initial data in my WPF (netcore3.1-windows) EFCore 5 application when I bind AnotherEntity's Name.
- The data does initially load in the same app but with WPF (net40) EFCore 6 Application from the Page's load:

```
    public partial class Entity
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
            
        public virtual AnotherEntity AnotherEntity { get; set; }
        ...
    }
    ...
    WPFPage()
    {
        _entities = DBContext.Entities.ToList();
    }
```

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding _entities}" ...> ...
    <GridView>                    
        <!--with FECore5 no data here. But in EF6 there is.-->
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Entity.AnotherEntityName}" 
        Header="Entity"
        Width="100"></GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
...
```

Unless I access and load Another database Entities from AnotherEntities property in the Application code:

```
    public AnotherWPFPage() { _anotherEntities = DBContext.AnotherEntities.ToList(); }
```

Or if I explicitly set the binding as

```xml
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Entity.AnotherEntity.AnotherEntityName}"
```

Is this due to the DataBase's scaffolding error by Fluent Api, xaml bindings feature or the EntityFrameworkCore's feature?.

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko, seems like I will have to create something like local variable  "var list = DBContext.AnotherEntities.ToList();" before _entities = DBContext.Entities.ToList(); before, Because only including AnotherEntities in query together with Entities doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an access your full code base, but I presume it's due to **EF Core** lazy loading feature and its dynamic proxies might not work with WPF binding.
In your code change this

```cs
_entities = DBContext.Entities.ToList();
```

To this

```cs
_entities = DBContext.Entities
    .Include(x => x.AnotherEntity)
    .ToList();
```